# Consumir Web Service Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, webservice

Buen día, se me ha pedido consumir un Web Service Rest en mi proyecto laravel, para traer datos de usuario de otro proyecto en Java, nunca lo he consumido web services, debido a eso, es posible realizarlo? De ser así podrían ayudarme con documentación o un ejemplo?

Comment: La respuesta es Si, por otro lado te recomiendo visites el [tour] y de paso leas [ask], las preguntas amplias, basadas en opiniones y que no muestran un punto de partida claro por donde comenzar a ayudar no suelen ser bien recibidas y terminan cerradas

Comment: puedes utilizar guzzle para hacer tu client o utilizar curl. Pero como te comentan arriba debes ser mas espesifico.